# I'm confused by the following sentence, can somebody explain to me about its sentence structure?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

> "She visits weekly to verify addresses, and **check residents have
>   registered all their details in accordance with the law**".

What does it really want to illustrate? Does it mean that she checks to confirm whether all of the residents have registered all their details in accordance with the law? Or is it just an assertive sentence? I'm so confused by this kind of structure, because I'm a Chinese speaker.

Comment: *Visit* is a typo for *visits*. *Verify addresses and check residents &c* is a conjoining of two infinitival VPs, both signaled by the preceding subordinator *to*--the same construction as "She visits weekly to gossip and snoop".

Comment: I still don't get it. I'm talking about this part- "check residents have registered all their details in accordance with the law" is she confirming? if yes, then why don't they put "whether" into this sentence to make it sound like she's confirming.

Comment: Not check/confirm *whether* but check/confirm *that*--subordinator *that* is almost always omissible.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree you can't leave out "whether"; I just thought it would help the OP understand the sentence.

Comment: @StoneyB what is the omissible subordinator of this this sentence? u mean "whether"? so this is what this sentence is really about, to check/confirm whether......

Comment: "She visits weekly to [verify addresses], and [check (that) residents have registered all their details in accordance with the law]". The two expressions in square brackets are purpose adjuncts introduced by the subordinator “to”. They give the purpose of her weekly visits. Note that you could also have “She visits weekly in order to … ”

Answer (score 1):

Adding what's left out (implicit in the sentence, as StoneyB explains in his comment):

She visits weekly to verify addresses and [to] check [that] residents have registered all their details in accordance with the law.

Yes, you could use **whether** instead of **that**.  Leaving out "that" makes it a little hard to get the meaning on first reading.

Also note it really shouldn't have a comma.

Comment: so the word "that" is kinda acting like the word "if" in this sentence. anyway, this sentence is all about confirming right?

Comment: It's about what you mean by "confirming."

Comment: I get it, so the omissible suborinator is actually the word "that". I really appreciated your helps, but I still don't know how to use this type of sentence structure properly. Anyway, I wanna reward u guys with some coins in return. Do they have coins here or other things for rewarding?